# Angular 8 and Kendo DropDownList Component: Why does a click on dropdown cause a "re-computation" of ngStyle inside an <ng-container> with an *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui

I edited this code on Stackblitz (the original link is the first link to Stackblitz here, under the "Primitive Values" section: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/value-binding/) in this way:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="example-config">
        Selected Value: {{selectedValue}}
    </div>
    <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="listItems" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"></kendo-dropdownlist>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listItems;">
      <span [ngStyle]="onChangeStyle(item)">{{item}}</span>
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public listItems: Array<string> = [ "Small", "Medium", "Large" ];
    public selectedValue: string = "Medium";

public ngOnInit() {
   console.log('onInit');
}

onChangeStyle(item) {
  console.log(item);
  return {'color': 'red'}
}

}
```

I cannot understand the reason why clicking the dropdown triggers the onChangeStyle() function for each item in the array; without even selecting it. The same happens when clicking out of the dropdown to close the items list. As demonstrated on the console, every click on the dropdown menù causes three executions of console.log().

Comment: using functions in angular template is an antipattern. Google it - you'll find tons of articles about this problem and how to solve it (ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush or computing everything beforehand)

Comment: You have been extremely helpful! With Pipes I solved the problem! Thank you!